# Will there be any Risk if we keeps on running our Activemq server for 1-2 months or for year

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

We have deployed ActiveMQ on out TC server so the script is written like :

1. Start TC server
2. Catalina.sh file will start ActiveMQ Broker before start TC server and then it starts ActiveMQ server
3. now when we stop our TC server or restart the server we don't do any restart with ActiveMQ or stop-start ActiveMQ server
4. We are planning to use same ActiveMQ server instance for a long time.
5. Our requirement is not to monitor queues
6. Also, our message will get listen as soon as they send so no pending messages. So no memory issue as once the message gets dequeued and it will get removed from data.db in KahaDB.

Daily some batch jobs will get load and it performs around 1000 message transactions, which gets listen at the same time.

So will there be any risk if we keep this running for a long duration( 3 months )?

We are planning to stop and start ActiveMQ server in every 3 months just for maintenance activity. will this be a good option?

Comment: Why "Our requirement is not to monitor queues"? This is a very strange requirement. Some kind of (automatic) monitoring is always needed.

Comment: Actually, we perform some database operation in between them. So we use this as functionality rather than statistics. moreover, Client doesn't want any activemq UI.

Comment: Have a look at the Azure platform.